# How to use Polymer (1.0) with Rails (4)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer, web-component

Now that Polymer (1.0) is "Production Ready" Which is the best way to use it on Rails (4) ?

I read a lot and I saw that all the solutions are deprecated, (For example using Gems like:  likepolymer-rails, emcee , etc)

I'm lost trying to create a good structure for the project, and the way to include all the polymer components, also I don't know if Sprocket could help or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE** *(16 June 2015)*: An **official package** has been released for `polymer-rails`. Please see [`polymer-elements-rails`](https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-elements-rails), which is the new and *official* repository which includes `iron-`, `paper-`, and `neon-elements`.

I will be keeping these forks up for the time being for anyone who may still have them already set as a dependency, but you will get identical functionality and prolonged support from using the official repository, so *I urge you to switch if you haven't.*

---

The [polymer-rails](https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-rails) project has been updated to 1.0, but unfortunately, the gems for the components have not yet. I've gone ahead and created the appropriate forks so that there's some working option in the meantime.

- https://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-iron-rails
- https://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-paper-rails
- https://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-neon-rails

Your gemfile should have:

```
gem 'polymer-rails'
gem 'polymer-iron-rails', :git => "git://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-iron-rails.git"
gem 'polymer-paper-rails', :git => "git://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-paper-rails.git"
gem 'polymer-neon-rails', :git => "git://github.com/vsimonian/polymer-neon-rails.git"
```

Then run `bundle`.

In `app/assets/components/application.html.erb` you set your dependencies:

```
//= require polymer/polymer
//= require iron-ajax/iron-ajax
//= require iron-input/iron-input
.....
```

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` should contain:

```
//= require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite
```

Your `.bowerrc` should have the 3rd-party component directory set:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vartan, this is the closest answer. But , are you going to mantain this gems?

Comment: @eveevans, please see my updated answer - it looks like the official repository just got finished up and thrown online several days ago! :)

Comment: Thanks! thats solves all the problems :)
Now, to contribute to the project

Comment: Hey! Just to clarify ... need I also run rails g polymer:component <component-name> for each component I want to include? As described here: https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-rails? @VartanSimonian

Comment: It seems like polymer-elements-rails is no longer being maintained. Which leaves us with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) to be a nice way to add this to your app.

[Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) is a proxy to [Bower](http://bower.io/) for generating gems from existing front end Javascript libraries and installing them on your behalf via bundler/your Gemfile.  This breaks your dependency on gem packagers for keeping front end Javascript libraries up to date.

Basically you'd add this to your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-polymer'
end
```

Then run `bundle install` (Make sure bundler is version 1.8.4 or above or it won't work w/ the aforementioned snippet)

Finally, add `//= require polymer` in the appropriate spot in application.js.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know about rails-assets. That seems like a really cool idea.

Comment: It works pretty well, but obviously you don't get rails specific functionality like generators and all that.  It's relatively simple to wrap most of the stuff w/ custom helpers though so that you can make it easy on yourself later on.

Comment: I think this will work for the JS assets, but no with the HTML templates (web components)

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago I had give a try with polymer, hope this can help you to get an idea

In **GemFile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'polymer-rails'
gem 'polymer-core-rails'
gem 'polymer-paper-rails'
```

In **app/assets/components/application.html.erb**

```
 //= require polymer/polymer
```

In  **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require polymer/platform
```

You show have **.bowerrc** files with the following content

```
{
 "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

Example view render with polymar

```
     <style>
         google-map {
             display: block;
             height: 600px;
         }
     </style>

     <h1>Polymer Rails Example</h1>

     <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fitToMarkers>
       <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"  draggable="true" title="Go Giants!"></google-map-marker>
       <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911"></google-map-marker>
     </google-map>

     <google-map disableDefaultUI showCenterMarker zoom="15"></google-map>
     <script>
         var map = document.querySelector('google-map');
         map.latitude = 37.77493;
         map.longitude = -122.41942;
         map.addEventListener('google-map-ready', function(e) {
             alert('Map loaded!');
         });
     </script>
```

You can take a look at my project using ploymer, not a nice coding but still you can get an idea form this commit [Github Repository](https://github.com/rokibulhassan/vehicle-routing-problem/commit/117b511dc7d76c16ec26f751544a15daf20fbead)

Comment: The problem with this is that gem 'polymer-core-rails' and  gem 'polymer-paper-rails' aren't ready for Polymer 1.0, they works with 0.5

Comment: I used those gems for  `gem polymer-rails (~> 0.1.9)`, I tried to give you an idea.

Comment: I understand, but the Core Element And Paper Elements, that comes with that gems are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`polymer-elements-rails` gem was created as there's not sense/possibility to separate them into different gems, as all of these components have circular dependencies. So it is hardly recommended to switch to this gem instead of using deprecated `polymer-paper-rails`, `polymer-iron-rails` etc. They will never be updated for `Polymer 1.0`.