# Rails + Google Polymer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer

I am getting this error when I try to hit my homepage. Trying to integrate Polymer into my Rails app. Any suggestions?

```
gem 'polymer-rails', '~> 0.1.9'
gem 'polymer-core-rails'
gem 'polymer-paper-rails
```

`` ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite' with type 'application/javascript'):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Polymer Rails Example</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    7:   <%= html_import_tag 'application'%>
    8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    9: </head>
  app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3181512530753562001_70181169375440' ``
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted the server after installing the gem ?

Comment: yes just did. same message....

Comment: what gem are you currently using ? polymer-rails ?

Comment: updated question w my gems

Comment: Have you done `rails g polymer:install` and `rails g polymer:component webcomponentsjs` ?

Comment: not the second part!

Comment: same error after rails g polymer:component webcomponentsjs

Comment: Just look into you project folder, can you find app/assets/components folder ?

Comment: updated question with screenshot showing folder

Comment: Based on this maybe you can try more official gem like:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30750022/4255944

Comment: Yes. I think maybe the gems I have listed above are incorrect. Thank you

Comment: @slindsey3000 did you ever get this working?